# How to export a list of numerical data to a file in the terminal?

Tags: files-and-directories, kernel, output

I have a very simple program that export a list to a data file in table form.

```
lst = {{1/10, 1/3}, {1/3, Pi}};
lst = N[lst, 10]
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["testlst.txt", lst, "Table"];
```

It works fine in the notebook interface. However, I want to execute it in the terminal, so I write it in a lst.m file:

```
lst = {{1/10, 1/3}, {1/3, Pi}};
lst = N[lst, 10]
(*I need to comment out this line because otherwise there will be error.*)
(*by the way, how to set it to current directory in script interface?*)
(*SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];*)
Export["testlst.txt", lst, "Table"];
```

Then I execute it with: `MathKernel -script lst.m` command. When I open testlst.txt I only found:

```
lst
```

in it.

### Edit

I made a mistake copy it to the script file. Somehow lst = {{1/10, 1/3}, {1/3, Pi}}; changes into t = {{1/10, 1/3}, {1/3, Pi}}; during the copy. No wonder the mistake.

The code works in terminal actually.

### ps:

I think in terminal, the default output directory is the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

Create try.m file with this in it:

```
SetDirectory["C:\\tmp"];
AppendTo[$Echo,"stdout"];
    SetOptions[ $Output, FormatType -> OutputForm ];
lst = {{1/10, 1/3}, {1/3, Pi}};
lst = N[lst, 10]
Export["testlst.txt", lst, "Table"];
```

Now from DOS window, type

```
>"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.3\math.exe" < try.m
```

Check the file

```
>type testlst.txt
0.1     0.3333333333
0.3333333333    3.141592654
>
```

it worked!

ps. I do not know how to set directory in script to the location of the script file. I always set it explicitly as in the above.

Comment: I actually made a mistake in the code when I copy the code to the script. Somehow `lst = {{1/10, 1/3}, {1/3, Pi}};` changes into `t = {{1/10, 1/3}, {1/3, Pi}};`. No wonder the  mistake.